# Uses of WCF Binding

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

From MSDN, we have the following definition of WCF Binding

> Bindings specify how a WCF service endpoint communicates with other endpoints.
>
> At its most basic, a binding must specify the transport (for example, HTTP or TCP) to use. You can also set other characteristics, such as security and transaction support, through bindings.

I am looking for practical uses of WCF. The scnearions in which people tweak the abilities of WCF Binding. Some of them are listed below.

1. **Exporting Metadata**: -  Custom policy assertions are exported by implementing the IPolicyExportExtension interface on a BindingElement class.

What are the other practical uses of Binding that you usually use?

Answer (score 2):

Bindings are useful when you want to expose the same end-point over different protocols - such as http or tcp. Also, you can have separate bindings in case you want to use the WS-* standards (for transactions/security capabilities) via the 'wsHttpBinding' pre-defined binding.

Sometimes, developers tweak the finer attributes on a binding. A good example is using 'streamedMode' of data transfer when large messages are involved. This eliminates the need of large memory buffers.